# Read Date from File Name in R and Append

Tags: r

I have below files in a folder

```
UPS_REPLEN_ORDERS_09102017_A
UPS_REPLEN_ORDERS_10102017_A
UPS_REPLEN_ORDERS_11102017_A
```

for another 60 days.

I need to extract the date from the respective files and insert in a data column in that file and then append all 60 days of files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about your end-goal?

Here's a way to get your files into R using regular expressions, and extract the dates from their names by substr. Since I don't understand what you mean to do with the files and dates after you've pulled them into R, I can't help you with your next steps.

I'm assuming that you've saved all of your target files to an accessible directory, that all files follow the convention you've given here (i.e., they begin with "UPS_REPLEN_ORDERS_", followed by an 8-digit date, followed by some other characters, possibly including a file extension), and that no other files in the directory follow this naming convention.

```
#set your working directory to wherever you've stored the files
setwd(dirname)

#declare your filename pattern using regular expressions
fpattern="^UPS_REPLEN_ORDERS_.*\\"

#find names matching this pattern in your current working directory
fnames=dir(getwd(),pattern=fpattern)

#extract the date from each filename
fdates=substr(fnames,19,26)

#loop to read files into R and modify as needed
nfiles=length(fnames)
for (i in 1:nfiles){
  infile=read.table(fnames[i]) #set read parameters as you need
  #other operations to be performed on the newly read-in file...
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir, Let me try to rephrase my question. I have many files with the name "UPS_REPLEN_ORDERS_DDMMYYYY_A.txt"  with 7 columns in it separated by "tab".
1. Extract date from File name
2. Put 8th column in file with Header as "Date"
3. copy the date in this new column as a date format.